# Get device token for iOS push notifications at certain point in app

Tags: ios, push-notification

I've tried Googling, and keep hitting the same sorts of answers, ie.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken 
{
    NSString *token = [[deviceToken description] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]];
    token = [token stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    NSLog(@"content---%@", token);
}
```

However, I'm struggling to see how I might call/invoke this method in my App Delegate at a given event.

In my app, the first screen they see is login/signup. So on success of signup, I'd like to grab the device token and send it to my server to save against that new user. How exactly can I invoke this method from within a View Controller (or wherever) at a given time/event of my choosing, (and not just when the app first boots up)?

Answer (score 0):

Hi try to use `NSUserDefaults` to store this data.

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:deviceTokenString forKey:@"deviceToken"];
```

And to get this data use:

```
NSUserDefaults *data = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];  
NSString *string = [data objectForKey:@"deviceToken"];
```

Comment: But how can I initially pop-up the permissions alert?

Comment: It will be automatically generate by iOS

Comment: Sure, but can I control when it does pop up?

Comment: I think I'm understanding it a bit better now. Even if someone sign in, then signs out, then creates a new account, it's still only one device token...because it's one device :)

So basically, ask for permissions to send push, store token in NSUserDefaults, then when they create an account, check to see if there's a token available for use?

Comment: When you read a token app is automatically ask to use you're device for push notifications.As i know now it is impossible to control with pop up but it is possible to do investigation about this.